# How to change the color of fireworks in fireworks-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the fireworks-js library. I need to change the colors of the fireworks to yellow.

How to make fireworks be the same color and not multi-colored?

I looked through the documentation, and did not find anything similar to specifying colors in the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set to hue to 60. This will make the fireworks yellow.

```
this.hue = {
  min: 60,
  max: 60
}
```